# How to find PDB id of an amino acid sequence

Tags: proteins, database, structural-biology, protein-structure, data

Suppose I have an amino acid sequence whose PDB id  is unknown. Is there in online server that can find the PDB id of the corresponding amino acid sequence?  is there any site that will find the pdb of a protein closest to the query protein?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to run a protein [BLAST search](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) at NCBI in which you specify the Protein Data Bank as your database, as in the example shown below:

[image: BLAST search against PDB]

The results will be all for proteins in the PDB.

Answer (score 1):

You can also search for amino acid sequences directly at the [PDB repository](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do#Subcategory-search_sequences).